# Doxygen tree-view shows only one group/module

Tags: doxygen

In a few different `.h` files, I have:

```
/**
 * @defgroup NAME <title>
 * <description>
 * @{
 */

// ...

/** @} */
```

that is, I define a few groups. In the generated HTML documentation, all the groups show up under Modules. However, in the tree view hierarchy, only the first group shows up. Why?

[image: Screenshot of missing modules]

If I enable the normal **Modules** menu via `DISABLE_INDEX = NO`, then the menu includes all 3 modules (as it should). So why doesn't the tree view show all 3?

---

I am using Doxygen 1.8.13.

For completeness, here is my `Doxyfile` showing only those values that differ from the default:

```
PROJECT_NAME            = "cdecl"
PROJECT_BRIEF           = "Compose and decipher C (or C++) type declarations or casts, aka ‘‘gibberish.’’"

INPUT                   = README.md src
EXTENSION_MAPPING       = l=C y=C
FILE_PATTERNS           = *.c *.h *.l *.md *.y
FILTER_PATTERNS         = "*.h=sed s/CDECL_[A-Z]*_INLINE/inline/"
PREDEFINED              = __GNUC__ \
                          WITH_READLINE \
                          WITH_TERM_COLUMNS
EXCLUDE                 = src/config.h \
                          src/lexer.c \
                          src/literals.h src/literals.c \
                          src/parser.c src/parser.h
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY        = docs

EXTRACT_ALL             = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE         = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC          = YES

DISABLE_INDEX           = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW       = YES

ALPHABETICAL_INDEX      = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE    = 1
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES    = YES
INTERNAL_DOCS           = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF       = YES
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT        = YES
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES   = 0
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C   = YES
QUIET                   = YES
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES      = NO
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS         = YES
TAB_SIZE                = 2
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT    = YES
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE  = README.md
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC        = YES

SOURCE_BROWSER          = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS     = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION  = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE  = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION     = YES
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (latest 1.8.13?). Can you complete the given .h file so it can directly be used to generate the required (wrong) output?

Comment: @albert Yes, using 1.8.13. I don't understand what you're asking about "completing the given `.h` file ...."

Comment: In your picture you have AST Nodes, Red-Black tree etc but in the code I don't see anything back from this.

Comment: @albert That's because I didn't post my entire source code base.

Comment: It is not necessary to post the code base but a simplified example showing the problem would be good to understand / reproduce the problem.

Comment: @albert Take the snippet I posted at the very top of my question. Put it in 3 different `.h` files. Make the group names different. There you go.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem, I always see all 3. I used the template as you specified only added 2 void function prototypes (to get also the triangle in front of the module sub pages. Probably I'm missing an important part in the setup of the project.

Comment: @albert Download cdecl https://github.com/paul-j-lucas/cdecl. Pick another source file, like `red_black.h`. Add a group via `@defgroup`.

Comment: I just downloaded the source, and added in the red_black.h 2 defgroup constructs as indicated in the header, further I left everything unchanged. I did see all the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite my using a force-reload in the browser, apparently that does *not* cause JavaScript to be reloaded.  The modules are done using JavaScript (why??). So the answer is that there's nothing wrong with Doxygen or my use of it: it's a stupid browser-caching issue.

In order to force-reload everything, I had to clear the browser cache to see the changes.  This is really annoying while writing the documentation.